# Arduino for loops not working as intended

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am new to arduino and am trying to make a `for loop` in it which just prints "Blink" using `Serial.println();` command 3 times, however it isn't working properly and it just prints "Blink" forever and doesn't stop at all. What am I doing wrong in the code below? Would be grateful to any help.

```c
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        Serial.println("Blink");
        delay(500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the for-loop inside the `loop()` function which runs endlessly.
Simply move it to `setup()`:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    Serial.println("Blink");
    delay(500);
  }
}

void loop() {
  
}
```

The arduino code is not a regular program.  you have to keep in mind that the arduino code is an operation system which has to run endlessly Otherwise the arduino will stop. therefore there are 2 functions, the `setup()` that runs one time and the `loop()` that runs infinity times.